# PID of a command executed in bash

Tags: linux, bash, process, pid

I need a linux / unix command that will execute another command and write the PID of the command it executes to a file... is there such a command?

I am not looking for any scheme that puts processes in the background and leverages the shell var `$!`

**Example:**

Assume the command I am looking for is `execwritepid`.  I need to be able to call:

```
execwritepid -e "/usr/bin/script -f sometext.log" -f /var/log/script.pid
```

Such that the PID of `script -f sometext.log` is written to `/var/log/script.pid`

[`script`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script) is the the command I'm executing.

The explicit suggestion, based on Daniel Pittman's answer is:

```
bash -c 'echo $$ > /var/log/script.pid && exec /usr/bin/script -f sometext.log'
```

Comment: Be careful: there is an actual UNIX/Linux command `script`; if that is the actual name, you should choose another.

Comment: @David, note what I said at the bottom of the question, I'm getting the pid for the UNIX script command you just mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want with this code:

```
echo $$ > /var/log/script.pid && exec /usr/bin/script
```

`exec` replaces the current process with another - which means that it retains the current pid.

If you want your parent script to carry on you can wrap that:

```
bash -c 'echo $$ && exec /usr/bin/script'
```

That will run the subcommand in a new shell, record the PID, then replace itself with the other process.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still having a problem... I can't figure out how to make the `exec` option send the `-f sometext.log` option to `script`

Comment: If you put `exec` in front of a regular bash command line it will replace itself with that command, rather than run the command and wait for it to exit.  So, `echo $$ > /var/lib/script.pid && exec /usr/bin/script -f sometext.log` should do exactly what you want.